# When is /etc/bash.bashrc invoked?

Tags: bash, configuration, bashrc

What is this file anyway? [Documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) makes no mention of it. And it's not supposed to be run automatically (version `4.3`, 2 February 2014):

> #### Invoked as an interactive login shell, or with --login
>
> When Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable. The --noprofile option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.
>
> When a login shell exits, Bash reads and executes commands from the file ~/.bash_logout, if it exists.
>
> #### Invoked as an interactive non-login shell
>
> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, Bash reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists. This may be inhibited by using the --norc option. The --rcfile file option will force Bash to read and execute commands from file instead of ~/.bashrc.
>
> So, typically, your ~/.bash_profile contains the line
>
> ```
> if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi
> ```
>
> after (or before) any login-specific initializations.
>
> #### Invoked non-interactively
>
> When Bash is started non-interactively, to run a shell script, for example, it looks for the variable BASH_ENV in the environment, expands its value if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as the name of a file to read and execute. Bash behaves as if the following command were executed:
>
> ```
> if [ -n "$BASH_ENV" ]; then . "$BASH_ENV"; fi
> ```
>
> but the value of the PATH variable is not used to search for the filename.
>
> As noted above, if a non-interactive shell is invoked with the --login option, Bash attempts to read and execute commands from the login shell startup files.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From Debian's `bash` [`README`](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Edoko/+junk/pkg-bash-debian/view/head:/README):

> 5. What is `/etc/bash.bashrc`? It doesn't seem to be documented.
>
> The Debian version of bash is compiled with a special option
> (`-DSYS_BASHRC`) that makes `bash` read `/etc/bash.bashrc` before `~/.bashrc`
> for interactive non-login shells. So, on Debian systems,
> `/etc/bash.bashrc` is to `~/.bashrc` as `/etc/profile` is to
> `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: It would appear that this -DSYS_BASHRC causes the `/etc/bash.bashrc` to be sourced, even when the `--rcfile` flag is used, which is in direct contradiction of what the man pages and documentation says. The only way I found to **only** use my rc file is to run bash in posix mode and use the ENV environment variable `ENV=myrc bash --posix`. If you don't want to be in posix mode, add `set +o posix` at the beginning of `myrc` file. (Does not work on Mac for unknown reason. However on Mac, `-DSYS_BASHRC` is not used, so you can use `--rcfile myrc` and get the desired result)

Comment: @Andy I strongly recommend filing a bug — run `reportbug bash` on your Debian system.

Answer (score 5):

Technically, `/etc/bash.bashrc` is invoked for interactive, non-login bash shells for all users.

However, usually `/etc/profile` (which is invoked for all login shells) calls `/etc/bash.bashrc` as well. So that means `/etc/bash.bashrc` is also invoked for all logins shells as well.

However, the first line usually checks quits if non-interactive.

**So in the end, effectively `/etc/bash.bashrc` is executed for all interactive bash shells (login and non-login). Think of it as the system-wide `~/.bashrc`**

Answer (score 1):

From `man bash`:

> When  an  interactive  shell that is not a login shell is started, bash
>        reads and executes commands from  /etc/bash.bashrc  and  ~/.bashrc,  if
>        these  files  exist.  This may be inhibited by using the --norc option.
>        The --rcfile file option will force bash to read and  execute  commands
>        from file instead of /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc.

The documentation you quote doesn't seem to be up-to-date.

Comment: I'm running `bash-4.3.33`, and my man pages don't mention `/etc/bash.bashrc` either. What version of `bash` and which distributuion are you running?

Comment: I'm running `arch linux`. I guess `debian` patches the man pages.

Comment: @x-yuri I only checked on my Debian derivative. I falsely assumed that bash is the same for all Linux distros.