# MacOS: What are the shell startup scripts for login and non login shells on Mac?

Tags: shell, macos

I have been learning about the startup scripts in Ubuntu that get run when you open a new shell: `/etc/profile, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.profile, ~/.bash_login` for login shells and
`/etc/bash.bashrc, ~/.bashrc` for non-login shells. I have a computer that runs Ubuntu, and the  order in which things run on that machine fits that order.

However, the files and the order they run in seems different for MacOS. I see that there is `/etc/bash` instead of `/etc/bash.bashrc`. In the home directory, I don't see `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_login`. Weirdest of all, when I put echo statements in all of these files, I see that I'm hitting both `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bash` whenever I open Terminal.app. Shouldn't I only hit the first one, seeing as I'm in a login shell? See below, the first three lines are my echo statements, and the fourth is me confirming that I'm in a login shell:

```
In /etc/profile
In /etc/bashrc
In ~/.bash_profile for user: davidkennell
Davids-MacBook-Pro:~ davidkennell$ shopt login_shell
login_shell     on
```

So far, I'm coming to the conclusion that the shell startup scripts for Mac are simply completely different from Ubuntu, despite both of them being Unix-based. Where can I get some info on which files are run when initializing login/non-login shells on Mac, and in what order?

Comment: Note that more correctly this is _in, specifically, the Bourne Again shell_ on MacOS.  Like on other operating systems, there are multiple shells available, and it is common for people to use the Z shell instead of the Bourne Again shell on MacOS, which would be a rather different question.

Comment: The bash manual is correct, but you have to read each startup file to see what files they include.

Comment: @JdeBP Ah, I didn't realize that different shells used completely different initialization scripts - I was under the impression that they all used the same first one or two startup files, which then sourced other files specific to the shells. I see that this was wrong now, and am now looking at shell-specific docs. This clears things up a lot.

Answer (score 4):

This is (mostly) described in [the Bash manual's section on Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files).

In brief:

- `/etc/profile` is sourced by login shells
- Then, the first available of `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile` is sourced.

  There is no  `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` by default in Ubuntu, so `~/.profile` is sourced. Ubuntu's (well, Debian's) `~/.profile` sources `~/.bashrc` when the shell is bash:

  ```
  # if running bash
  if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
      # include .bashrc if it exists
      if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
      . "$HOME/.bashrc"
      fi
  fi
  ```

  But this is not generally true for `~/.profile` in other distributions or OSs.
- Debian (and hence Ubuntu) uses [a special option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187372/70524) to enable sourcing of `/etc/bash.bashrc`. This is not used in macOS. Instead, at least in Catalina, `/etc/profile` sources `/etc/bashrc` (much like Ubuntu's `~/.profile`):

  ```
  # cat /etc/profile
  # System-wide .profile for sh(1)

  if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
      eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
  fi

  if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
      [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
  fi
  ```